# angularjs bind input text field with drop down and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

i have this radio buttons and drop down menu that are synchronized dynamically. Im trying to include an input box (the selection field) where the user can type their choice as a number, for example if the user types 3 in the input box, the drop down menu and radio buttons should dynamically change as well to orange in this case and if the user types 2 to banana and so on.
And also, I'm trying to list the selected fruit in the answer field dynamically. thanks for the help

```js
 var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [
        {name : "apple"},
        {name : "banana"},
        {name : "orange"},
        {name : "melon"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="aCtrl">

<p>choose a fruit</p>

<select ng-model="selectFruit" ng-options="x.name for x in fruits">
</select>
<input name='a' type="radio" ng-model="selectFruit" ng-value="fruits[0]"> apple
<input name='a' type="radio" ng-model="selectFruit"  ng-value="fruits[1]" > banana
<input name='a' type="radio" ng-model="selectFruit"  ng-value="fruits[2]"> orange
<input name='a' type="radio" ng-model="selectFruit"  ng-value="fruits[3]"> melon

 <p>Selection <input type="text" ng-model="selectFruit" /></p>

 <p>Answer</p>
<div ng-switch="selectFruit">
<div ng-switch-when="apple">
<h1>apple</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle :   https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27636/

`<p>Selection <input type="text" ng-model="selectFruit" ng-change="change(selectFruit)" /></p`>

**Script:**

```
$scope.change = function(a){
      $scope.selectFruit = $scope.fruits[a];
    }
```

When you enter a number(index) in textbox it will selects the corresponding item.

Comment: it works fine but how can i change it so that instead of entering 0 for apple the user has to enter 1 , 2 for banana and so on? i know arrays start at 0 but i got stuck trying to fix that. thanks

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you want to start from 1,2,3... Instead of zero?

Comment: yeah, exactly. Also, how can I display the answer dynamically at the bottom after Answer?

Comment: Updated my ans.